# How to do conditional nested lookup search in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections in mongodb 4.2:

- article - [Id,ArticletypeId,BestResponseId,Topic,PredecessorId]

  ```
    { Id: 1, ArticleTypeId:1, BestResponseId:2, Topic:"XYZ" },
    { Id: 2, ArticleTypeId:2, PredecessorId:1 },
    { Id: 3, ArticleTypeId:2, PredecessorId:1 },
    { Id: 4, ArticleTypeId:2, BestResponseId:5, Topic:"ABC" },  
    { Id: 5, ArticleTypeId:1, PredecessorId:4 },
    { Id: 6, ArticleTypeId:2, PredecessorId:4 }
  ```
- result-[Id,ArticleId,ResultTypeId]

  ```
  { Id: 1, ArticleId:1, ResultTypeId:2 },
  { Id: 2, ArticleId:2, ResultTypeId:2 },
  { Id: 3, ArticleId:2, ResultTypeId:2 },
  { Id: 4, ArticleId:3, ResultTypeId:2 },
  { Id: 5, ArticleId:2, ResultTypeId:2 },
  { Id: 6, ArticleId:4, ResultTypeId:2 },
  { Id: 7, ArticleId:5, ResultTypeId:2 },
  { Id: 8, ArticleId:6, ResultTypeId:2 },
  { Id: 9, ArticleId:6, ResultTypeId:2 }
  ```
- In article collection, BestResponseId is the ArticleId of the best response to the given article,i.e., for ArticleId = 1 with Topic"XYZ", the best response is ArticleId=2 and so on.
- The PredecessorId indicates which article the response is for.
- In result collection, ArticleId is the foreign key referencing article-Id
- ***We need to find the list of topics where the Count(ResultTypeId=2) is greater in AnyResponse than the BestResponse***,so in the below example:
- For the results from 1-5,The Count(ResultTypeId = 2 ) for ArticleId(2) is 2, but for other response against the same article the Count(ResultTypeId=2) is 1,so best response got the best result, we wont consider in output.
- But here for the other results from 6-9:The Count(ResultTypeId = 2 ) for ArticleId(5) is 1,where as Count(ResultTypeId = 2 ) for ArticleId(5) is 2,
  hence the expected output will be the
- Topic
- "ABC"
- So, basically, you do a join between article & article[on Id and
  PredecessorId,self join], get the list of PredecessorIds alongwith
  which one among them is BestResponseId,so the first level of lookup
  should give output like:

  ```
  PredecessorId|ArticleId|IsBestResponse
  1           |2       |  true
  1           |3       |  false
  4           |5       |  true
  4           |6       |  false
  ```
- Now once you join this with result(ArticleId),and do the count of
  ResultTypeId=2 groupBy ArticleId.  So after the second level of
  lookup,the output will be:

  ```
  ArticleId|PredecessorId|IsBestResponse|ResultType2_Count
      2     |   1         |    true      |  3
      3     |   1         |    false     |  1
      5     |   4         |    true      |  1
      6     |   4         |    false     |  2
  ```
- Now, we need to output the topic name for the predecessors of
  Articles, for whom the IsBestResponse=false but ResultType2_Count
  greater than the ResultType2_Count of the article for which
  IsBestResponse=true belonging to the same predecessor.
- So between ArticleId 5 and 6, this condition satisfies.And the
  corresponding Topic of their Predecessor ["ABC"]is expected output.
- If, 2 & had satisfied the same condition,we would have printed "XYZ"
  as well.But,it's not.

I am kind of new to mongodb and lookup, this is what I have done so far:

```
db.article.aggregate([
{
$lookup:{
from:"article",
localField:"ArticleId",
foreignField:"PredecessorId",
as:"articles"
}
},
{$unwind:"$articles"},
{$lookup:{
from:"result",
localField:"answers.Id",
foreignField:"ArticleId",
as:"articles"
}},
{$unwind:"$articles"}
])
```

I am sure I need to do $sum or $count in the second level of nested look up.
Is there any way I can accomplish it inside the same query?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have flexibility over the data model?   I sense an array of info could help here; there is something relational-ish about the current setup.

Comment: Yes, you are right @BuzzMoschetti, it's kind of relational-ish, I have simplified it that way, the actual structure is more robust but not necessary in current context. And yes, we can modify the data model, if required as it's already a subset.

Comment: You write: *For the results from 1-5,The Count(ResultTypeId = 2 ) for ArticleId(2) is 2, ...*  Isn't it 3?

Comment: Try actually showing the data as "text" in the question instead of posting pictures. Then show an actual expected result that is possible to obtain from the data included in the question. In that way people can actually use your data ( really hard to use pictures without typing it in ) and have a reference to a reproducible result. Simply showing the expected result will be a lot clearer than your current *"list of conditions"* which are frankly a little obtuse. **"Show"** and don't "tell". Makes a better question.

Comment: @Neil, thanks for the suggestion, I have updated as requested!

Comment: So that data could do with some corrections. You don't have keys without any value. Since MongoDB is "schemaless" then if there is no value then you probably just don't have the key in the document at all. You also seem to be missing the point of "expected output". Rather than putting comments next items in one of the collections. Show the actual "joined" output you expect. Give us the point and make it very clear. I suspect what you are basically asking for is identifying for  `"ABC"` and `"XYZ"` where the total count of something is greater than something else, but actual results are needed

Comment: Sorry, done again!

Comment: @Buzz, you are right!For the results from 1-5,The Count(ResultTypeId = 2 ) for ArticleId(2) is 2, ... Isn't it 3,yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it would appear that what you are looking for is actually the following:

```
db.article.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Topic": { "$exists": true } } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "article",
    "let": { "id": "$Id", "bestResponse": "$BestResponseId" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { 
        "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$$id", "$PredecessorId" ] }
      }},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "result",
        "let": { "articleId": "$Id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "ResultTypeId": 2,
            "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$$articleId", "$ArticleId" ] }
          }},
          { "$count": "count" }
        ],
        "as": "results"
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "results": "$$REMOVE",
        "count": { "$sum": "$results.count" },
        "isBestResponse": { "$eq": ["$$bestResponse", "$Id"] }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "responses"
  }},
  { "$match": {
     "$expr": {
       "$gt": [
         { "$max": "$responses.count" },
         { "$arrayElemAt": [
           "$responses.count",
           { "$indexOfArray": [ "$responses.Id", "$BestResponseId" ] }
         ]}
       ]
     }
  }}
])
```

And that would provide ( as more MongoDB like output than the relational output you are explaining as ) :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5da1206f22b8db5a00668cc4"),
        "Id" : 4,
        "ArticleTypeId" : 2,
        "BestResponseId" : 5,
        "Topic" : "ABC",
        "responses" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5da1206f22b8db5a00668cc5"),
                        "Id" : 5,
                        "ArticleTypeId" : 1,
                        "PredecessorId" : 4,
                        "count" : 1,
                        "isBestResponse" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5da1206f22b8db5a00668cc6"),
                        "Id" : 6,
                        "ArticleTypeId" : 2,
                        "PredecessorId" : 4,
                        "count" : 2,
                        "isBestResponse" : false
                }
        ]
}
```

Now I'll walk through that and explain why it is so.

Firstly you want a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage right at the start of the pipeline to just exclude anything other than those valid `Topic` results. This uses a simple [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) in order to just retrieve those results with that field, and then hence meet the condition for the first "join".

The actual [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is going to use the [modern form with a `pipeline` expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries). This is for the two primary reasons of:

- We actually want an "inner" [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) expression to get results from the other collection.
- We want to do manipulations on the results *before* they are returned *"as an array"* which is the output of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) **always**. This is more efficient that manipulating the "array" returned *afterwards*.

One thing to note in this syntax is the `let` expression:

```
    "let": { "id": "$Id", "bestResponse": "$BestResponseId" },
```

The most *common* use case here is to provide values from the *parent* document which can be used in the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) logic within an initial [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) indicating the "join" conditions, i.e which field value matches for *local* and *foreign*. But in this case we actually have another valid use, notably for the `bestResponse` value declared.

Note once we have "joined" which is the *"self-join"* part in order to get the relevant child items, then the very next thing we want is another [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) nested within this `pipeline` expression. In this case we want *it's* initial [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage in *it's* own `pipeline` expression to use an addition constraint for `ResultTypeId: 2`, which is part of what the question asks. This is basically how you can include multiple conditions on a "join".

Since we really are not interested in the nested details from the `result` collection and really do no need a `results` array within the other array of *"children"*, then to ***reduce*** the results we use the [`$count`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) pipeline stage within this *sub-pipeline*.

Now that's not completely what you want, so in the initial [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operation within it's `pipeline` expression, you then add the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage to manipulate what is essentially an *array* in the `results` property ( albeit of just a single document with one property ) into just being a single property in each child with a singular value via the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator. You could do:

```
"count": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$results.count", 0 ] }
```

And that would be the same result, but it's notably a *longer* expression than just `"$sum": "$results.count"`.

The other thing you wanted ( though not really necessary for the remaining logic ) is to identify which *"child"* actually matches the `BestResponseId` value. This is actually what we use the `bestResponse` variable we declared earlier. Since that is the value in the *parent*, then this is processed against each *child* from ***within the pipeline*** and simply returns `true` or `false` where that current *child* `Id` field actually matched that value from the *parent*.

Once out of the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline stage, the only thing left to do is determine *after the "join"* which of the result documents actually meets the condition of having an article with a higher results count than the one marked as the *"BestResponse"*. This is done with another [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage, which employs the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator again.

In short, the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) is used to obtain the *maximum* of the `count` values returned within each *child* entry as the `responses` array from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). This is compared to the value obtained by the [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) operator matching against the values of the `Id` fields in the `responses` array where they match the parent `BestResponseId` ( or alternately, where the `isBestResponse` is `true`. But this is why I noted that was not needed ). Having that matching "index value", then you can extract a singular value of the `count` property from that array via [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and do the comparison. If it's actually a *greater than* number, then that document qualifies for a returned result.

Of course you can simply return the document with original fields if you want using another [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or even [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/), or [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to *"denormalize"* if you again really want a result that looks the same as an SQL "join" result. But the basic logic really only needs the three stages ( and a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) *within* a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) ) for the essential parts of implementation.

Comment: Thank you Neil for your effort and detail explanation,I am sure in future this post will help other community members!

Comment: Superb example of `$lookup` within the `pipeline` of a parent `$lookup`.